# Best practice to set constant parameters for inheritance class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class `GUI` defined as follows:

```
table_color = "red"

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.draw_table()

    def draw_table(self):
        print "table color: ", table_color
```

and I want to define a child class `GUI_child` based on GUI:

```
table_color = "blue"

class GUI_child(GUI):
    def __init__(self):
        GUI.__init__(self)
```

However the above `GUI_child` does not work and prints "red". I have a bunch of variables like `table_color` that are only used once at initialization. I know I can define `table_color` as a class variable, or define `draw_table()` again in `GUI_child`, but feel that these may not be the best option.

(Edit: Since these variables are used only once and I am not going to change or access them, setting them as class variables seems redundant. If I redefine the `draw_table()` it will just be copy-paste, which in my perspective is not a good practice either.)

What is the best practice for such usage?

Comment: I'm tempted to make a joke that "inheritance" and "best practice" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Why do you *feel that these may not be the best option*?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Since these variables are used only once and I am not going to change or access them, setting them as class variables seems redundant. If I redefine the `draw_table()` it will just be copy-paste, which in my perspective is not a good practice either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the definition `table_color = "red"` into the very beginning of the `class GUI` definition and reference it with `self.table_color` in the methods of the class.  Moving it into the class makes it a class attribute that will be inherited by derived classes.

However you can override its value in a child class by just redefining it in the child class definition (in the same manner) to override the one in the parent class that would otherwise be inherited.

Here's what I mean:

```
class GUI:
    table_color = "red"

    def __init__(self):
        self.draw_table()

    def draw_table(self):
        print("table color: {}".format(self.table_color))

class GUI_child(GUI):
    table_color = "blue"

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI_child, self).__init__()

gui = GUI()              # -> table color:  red
gui_child = GUI_child()  # -> table color:  blue
```

**Note** that according the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants), constants should be all uppercase. This means `table_color` should be changed to `TABLE_COLOR`.